# AngularJS dynamically load content in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building an AngularJS application where I want to dynamically load different html templates based on where it was called from. I am new to AngularJS, so I may well be wide of the mark with this approach.

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectsCtrl" ng-init="getProjects()">
    <div ng-repeat="project in projects>
        <button ng-click="">Create New Project</button>
        <button ng-click="">Cancel</button>
        <div ng-repeat="task in projects.tasks>
            <button ng-click="">Create New Task</button>
            <button ng-click="">Cancel</button>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
<focus-pane></focus-pane>
```

**app.js**

```
var projectsApp = angular.module('projectsApp', []);

projectsApp.directive('focusPane', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
            // this template loading should be dynamic
            templateUrl: '_create_project.html'
    };
});

concernsApp.controller('ProjectsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ) {
    ...
});
```

So, what I want to do is be able to two things when the 'Create New Project' button is clicked:

1. pass in the `project` or `task` object and use this in the `focusPane` directive.
2. pass in a name of a template to load dynamically in the directive.

I'm thinking, in pseudo-code, the html should look something like this:

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectsCtrl" ng-init="getProjects()">
    <div ng-repeat="project in projects>
        <button ng-click="createProject(project, '_create_project.html')">Create New Project</button>
        <button ng-click="">Cancel</button>
        <div ng-repeat="task in projects.tasks>
            <button ng-click="createProject(task, '_create_task.html')">Create New Task</button>
            <button ng-click="">Cancel</button>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
<focus-pane></focus-pane>
```

..and then I would declare these functions in the `ProjectsCtrl`. However, as I said, I'm just getting into AngularJS and I'm not sure this is the right path at all. In the AngularJS Docs I couldn't find much info on dynamically loading things in a directive.

Comment: Create a provider, which is configurable and available when directives will be started.

Comment: It is not recommended to load data in a directive. Preferably you create a service (that handles the various $http requests) and inject that in your controller. In general: Angular can be somewhat confusing at first glance. I highly recommend this video as a start point to get familiar with the specifics of Angular: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

Comment: So, a directive is not the best way to achieve my intention?

Comment: nope, a directive is a way to extend the html with new functionalities. You could consider using the controller inside the directive. That would be a better way, but in general loading data should be done in a service (injected in a directive or controller)

Comment: So, maybe a route provider which loads different templates depending on an appended url name, such as `#create-project`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the comments made earlier are correct (depending upon what context your working in), but it is still possible none the less to create a directive that will load dynamic templates for you. Here is an example. http://jsfiddle.net/joshkurz/T42xQ/5/

```
.directive('dynamicTemplate', ['$compile', '$templateCache',         function($compile, $templateCache){
return {  
    scope: { templateVar: '@'},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

        scope.test = 'Hello World';
        scope.$watch('templateVar', function(newV,oldV){

            if(newV !== undefined){
                var newElement = $compile($templateCache.get(newV).trim())(scope);
                element.html('');
                element.append(newElement[0]);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

}]);

I find sometimes when creating directives they can actually have requirements to control what data is requested. After all that is what ngView does right? its a directive too. You just have to make sure that that you have all the data before any DOM manipulation starts.